# Drupal 7 FAPI: When is the 'committed' flag set?

Tags: 7, forms

I built a custom form using FAPI in Drupal 7 that suddenly stopped working. (It's in a development area, so someone could've introduced something that inadvertently interfered.) I found that the submit handler was never called, due to `$form_state['submitted']` being false. I assume that normal (non-AJAX) submit is supposed to set this flag, but I've grepped and stepped through the code and can't find where it's done. (Working on the assumption that if I found where it's set, I can maybe find out why it's never getting there...)

I was able to get things working again by setting the flag myself in the validation routine after a value came back that I know means the user is done. But this seems like a terrible hack, and may have unintended consequences down the road. I don't see any other modules doing this.

Can anyone tell me where this flag is set, so I can try to backtrack and find out what happened?